# Flickr link to Query with WOE-id and tags

Tags: flickr, phpflickr

I've made a query with the Flickr api to display pictures in a region with a WOE id and with some tags.

I'm querying the [flickr.photos.search](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) method with these options:

```
$options = array('privacy_filter'=>1,
                    'woe_id' => $woe,
                    'tag_mode'=> 'any',
                    'per_page'=> 6,
                    'sort' =>'interestingness-desc',
                    'tags' =>'some, tags'
                  );
```

It displays 6 pictures. I want to redirect the visitor of my page to a Flickr page which displays the results of my query in their environment.

Does anyone know how I can establish this?

Answer (score 0):

By flickr.photos.search API, you can get the id, and secret for each photo. To get the URL of each photo in Flickr, you have to do another query flickr.photos.getinfo with photo id and secret. Then you will find the url metadata and show the result in Flickr environment.